# I get ioncube and php error when installing Vestacp

Tags: php, centos, ioncube, vesta

I've installed vestacp on my centos 7 server. I got an ioncube error during the installation. Please help if I got php errors while updating php.

My Vestacp options. I have set Nginx-Php FPM and got an ioncube error in the installation. I am getting php error while doing 7.3 with php 5.6 update. Help.

Error messages:

```html
mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/vesta/data/ips/’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘/usr/local/vesta/data/ips/185.130.59.17’
sed: can't read /usr/local/vesta/data/users/*/dns/*.conf: No such file or directory
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
Installing : vesta-ioncube-0.9.8-23.x86_64                            193/199
/usr/local/vesta/ioncube/ioncube.sh: line 19: /etc/init.d/vesta: No such file or directory
warning: %post(vesta-ioncube-0.9.8-23.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 127
Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm package vesta-ioncube-0.9.8-23.x86_64



 Updating   : php-pecl-zip-1.15.4-1.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64                  15/50
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: bcmath: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so: undefined symbol: _zend_list_find), /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gmp.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/gmp.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/gmp.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/lib64/php/modules/gmp.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/gmp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/imap.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/imap.so: undefined symbol: _zend_list_delete), /usr/lib64/php/modules/imap.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/imap.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ldap.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so: undefined symbol: _zend_hash_index_update_or_next_insert), /usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so: undefined symbol: _zend_list_delete), /usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'posix.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/posix.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/posix.so: undefined symbol: _zval_dtor_func), /usr/lib64/php/modules/posix.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/posix.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: recode: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'shmop.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so: undefined symbol: _zend_list_find), /usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/shmop.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'soap.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvmsg.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/sysvmsg.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/sysvmsg.so: undefined symbol: _zval_dtor_func), /usr/lib64/php/modules/sysvmsg.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/sysvmsg.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sysvsem: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvshm.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/sysvshm.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/sysvshm.so: undefined symbol: _zend_list_delete), /usr/lib64/php/modules/sysvshm.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/sysvshm.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'tidy.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/tidy.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/tidy.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init), /usr/lib64/php/modules/tidy.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/tidy.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'twig.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/twig.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/twig.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init), /usr/lib64/php/modules/twig.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/twig.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0






Installing : php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.2-2.el7.remi.7.3.x86_64                25/50
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: bcmath: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'json' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'twig.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/twig.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/twig.so: undefined symbol: zval_used_for_init), /usr/lib64/php/modules/twig.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/twig.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Such message during major version update (e.g. 5.6 => 7.2) is expected.

Whatever the installation order is, you have, at some point the engine update, and then the extensions, so the API doesn't match and is reported.

After the transaction, and simple "php -v" should report that everything is ok.

Error may still appears for manually installed extension, build form sources, which have to be reinstalled.